# Nesting two ng-repeats

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to show some data in a table with two ng-repeats. But the second ng-repeat doesn't seem to work. This is what I'm trying:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="admin-detail-rows" ng-repeat="lesson in lessons | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
       <div ng-repeat="group in lesson.groups">
           <td>{{ working_days[lesson.day - 1] }}</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.start_time }} - {{ lesson.end_time }}</td>
           <td>{{ group.available_seats ? group.max_seats - group.available_seats : 0 }} / {{ group.max_seats }}</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.room }}</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.teacher }}</td>
           <td>{{ group.group_name }}</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.groupDetails  }}</td>
           <td ng-click="removeLesson(lesson)" class="delete-button">✖</td>
      </div>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

But it never does the second repeat more than once, and it doesn't know a lot of the properties.

A lesson that I'm iterating through in the first ng-repeat could look like this:

```
 {
    "id":140,
    "course_id":156,
    "start_time":"08:45",
    "end_time":"10:30",
    "day":2,
    "type":1,
    "course_description":"The Business Dimension of Europe (lecture; group P:3+Q:3+R:3)",
    "room":"OVk.41 left",
    "teacher":"Test teacher","created_at":"2017-04-11 13:43:29",
    "course": {
    "id":156,
    "code":"Test code",
    "name":"The Business Dimension of Europe",
    "credits":3,
    "category_id":20,
    "entry_requirements":null,
    "assessment_materials":null,
    "study_materials":null,
    "outline":null,
    "description":null,
    "created_at":"2017-04-11 13:41:45"
},
    "groups":[{
    "id":181,"timetable_id":140,
    "course_id":156,
    "group_name":"P",
    "group_details":null,
    "max_seats":3,
    "available_seats":-4,
    "created_at":"2017-04-11 13:43:29"
    }, {
    "id":182,
    "timetable_id":140,
    "course_id":156,
    "group_name":"Q",
    "group_details":null,"max_seats":3,
    "available_seats":null,
    "created_at":"2017-04-11 13:43:29"
    },{"id":183,
    "timetable_id":140,
    "course_id":156,
    "group_name":"R",
    "group_details":null,
    "max_seats":3,"available_seats":null,
    "created_at":"2017-04-11 13:43:29"}
    ]}
```

Assigning the lesson to the scope:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
  return lessonsService.getLessons();
}, function (lessons) {
  $scope.lessons = lessons;
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hey there is some issue with json structure and ng-repeat statement.

```js
 angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
 
   $scope.lessons  =[{
 "id": 140,
 "course_id": 156,
 "start_time": "08:45",
 "end_time": "10:30",
 "day": 2,
 "type": 1,
 "course_description": "The Business Dimension of Europe (lecture; group P:3+Q:3+R:3)",
 "room": "OVk.41 left",
 "teacher": "Kerkhof van de B.K.W.",
 "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29",
 "course": {
  "id": 156,
  "code": "ES-ISBMDIMEUR-16",
  "name": "The Business Dimension of Europe",
  "credits": 3,
  "category_id": 20,
  "entry_requirements": null,
  "assessment_materials": null,
  "study_materials": null,
  "outline": null,
  "description": null,
  "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:41:45"
 },
 "groups": [{
  "id": 181,
  "timetable_id": 140,
  "course_id": 156,
  "group_name": "P",
  "group_details": null,
  "max_seats": 3,
  "available_seats": -4,
  "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29"
 }, {
  "id": 182,
  "timetable_id": 140,
  "course_id": 156,
  "group_name": "Q",
  "group_details": null,
  "max_seats": 3,
  "available_seats": null,
  "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29"
 }, {
  "id": 183,
  "timetable_id": 140,
  "course_id": 156,
  "group_name": "R",
  "group_details": null,
  "max_seats": 3,
  "available_seats": null,
  "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29"
 }]
}];
          
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table>
    <tr  ng-repeat="lesson in lessons ">
       <div ng-repeat="group in lesson.groups">
           <td>{{ working_days[lesson.day - 1] }} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.start_time }} - {{ lesson.end_time }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
           <td>{{ group.available_seats  }} / {{ group.max_seats }}&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.room }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.teacher }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
           <td>{{ group.group_name }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.groupDetails  }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
           <td ng-click="removeLesson(lesson)" class="delete-button">✖</td>
      </div>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

here is the json structure:

```js
[{
 "id": 140,
 "course_id": 156,
 "start_time": "08:45",
 "end_time": "10:30",
 "day": 2,
 "type": 1,
 "course_description": "The Business Dimension of Europe (lecture; group P:3+Q:3+R:3)",
 "room": "OVk.41 left",
 "teacher": "Kerkhof van de B.K.W.",
 "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29",
 "course": {
  "id": 156,
  "code": "ES-ISBMDIMEUR-16",
  "name": "The Business Dimension of Europe",
  "credits": 3,
  "category_id": 20,
  "entry_requirements": null,
  "assessment_materials": null,
  "study_materials": null,
  "outline": null,
  "description": null,
  "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:41:45"
 },
 "groups": [{
  "id": 181,
  "timetable_id": 140,
  "course_id": 156,
  "group_name": "P",
  "group_details": null,
  "max_seats": 3,
  "available_seats": -4,
  "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29"
 }, {
  "id": 182,
  "timetable_id": 140,
  "course_id": 156,
  "group_name": "Q",
  "group_details": null,
  "max_seats": 3,
  "available_seats": null,
  "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29"
 }, {
  "id": 183,
  "timetable_id": 140,
  "course_id": 156,
  "group_name": "R",
  "group_details": null,
  "max_seats": 3,
  "available_seats": null,
  "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29"
 }]
}]
```

Hope it will work for you thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your inner ng-repeat should be **`groups`** instead of **`group`**,

```
<div ng-repeat="group in lesson.groups">
```

**DEMO**

```js
 angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
 
   $scope.lessons  =[{
 "id": 140,
 "course_id": 156,
 "start_time": "08:45",
 "end_time": "10:30",
 "day": 2,
 "type": 1,
 "course_description": "The Business Dimension of Europe (lecture; group P:3+Q:3+R:3)",
 "room": "OVk.41 left",
 "teacher": "Kerkhof van de B.K.W.",
 "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29",
 "course": {
  "id": 156,
  "code": "ES-ISBMDIMEUR-16",
  "name": "The Business Dimension of Europe",
  "credits": 3,
  "category_id": 20,
  "entry_requirements": null,
  "assessment_materials": null,
  "study_materials": null,
  "outline": null,
  "description": null,
  "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:41:45"
 },
 "groups": [{
  "id": 181,
  "timetable_id": 140,
  "course_id": 156,
  "group_name": "P",
  "group_details": null,
  "max_seats": 3,
  "available_seats": -4,
  "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29"
 }, {
  "id": 182,
  "timetable_id": 140,
  "course_id": 156,
  "group_name": "Q",
  "group_details": null,
  "max_seats": 3,
  "available_seats": null,
  "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29"
 }, {
  "id": 183,
  "timetable_id": 140,
  "course_id": 156,
  "group_name": "R",
  "group_details": null,
  "max_seats": 3,
  "available_seats": null,
  "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29"
 }]
}];
          
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table>
    <tr  ng-repeat="lesson in lessons ">
       <div ng-repeat="group in lesson.groups">
           <td>{{ working_days[lesson.day - 1] }} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.start_time }} - {{ lesson.end_time }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
           <td>{{ group.available_seats  }} / {{ group.max_seats }}&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.room }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.teacher }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
           <td>{{ group.group_name }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.groupDetails  }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
           <td ng-click="removeLesson(lesson)" class="delete-button">✖</td>
      </div>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo that slipped in during ctrl+z'ing my code and posting it here. I already tried doing that before posting here and still nothing

Comment: is it working when you remove | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse"

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: I have added it in the question

Comment: are you sure this is what present inside the lessons? put a console.log and see

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I already used a console.log with JSON.stringify and posted  what it returned here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146164/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-snackoverflow).

Answer (score 0):

As your row should show lessons - your first ng-repeat should be at tr
and then second ng-repeat at td level.
HTML:

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<table>
<thead>
        <tr>
          <td>working_days</td>
          <td>lesson.start_time - lesson.end_time</td>
          <td>group.available_seats / group.max_seats</td>
          <td>lesson.room</td>
          <td>lesson.teacher</td>
          <td>group.group_name</td>
          <td>lesson.groupDetails </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
  <tbody  ng-repeat="lesson in lessons ">
  <tr ng-repeat="group in lesson.groups">
     <td >working_days {{lesson.day - 1}}</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.start_time }} - {{ lesson.end_time }}</td>
           <td >{{ group.available_seats  }} / {{ group.max_seats }}</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.room }}</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.teacher }}</td>
           <td>{{ group.group_name }}</td>
           <td>{{ lesson.groupDetails  }}</td>
           <td ng-click="removeLesson(lesson)" class="delete-button">✖</td>
  </tr>

      </tbody>

</table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('testApp',[]).controller('testCtrl', function($scope){

        $scope.lessons  =[
    {
        "id": 140,
        "course_id": 156,
        "start_time": "08:45",
        "end_time": "10:30",
        "day": 2,
        "type": 1,
        "course_description": "The Business Dimension of Europe (lecture; group P:3+Q:3+R:3)",
        "room": "OVk.41 left",
        "teacher": "Kerkhof van de B.K.W.",
        "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29",
        "course": {
            "id": 156,
            "code": "ES-ISBMDIMEUR-16",
            "name": "The Business Dimension of Europe",
            "credits": 3,
            "category_id": 20,
            "entry_requirements": null,
            "assessment_materials": null,
            "study_materials": null,
            "outline": null,
            "description": null,
            "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:41:45"
        },
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": 181,
                "timetable_id": 140,
                "course_id": 156,
                "group_name": "P",
                "group_details": null,
                "max_seats": 3,
                "available_seats": -4,
                "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29"
            },
            {
                "id": 182,
                "timetable_id": 140,
                "course_id": 156,
                "group_name": "Q",
                "group_details": null,
                "max_seats": 3,
                "available_seats": null,
                "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29"
            },
            {
                "id": 183,
                "timetable_id": 140,
                "course_id": 156,
                "group_name": "R",
                "group_details": null,
                "max_seats": 3,
                "available_seats": null,
                "created_at": "2017-04-11 13:43:29"
            }
        ]
    }
];

 });
```

And for you Working days, it should be working_days {{lesson.day - 1}} unless if you have a different list variable
Check the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sathvike/efq9djpy/